# Accessing memory of Sony Ericsson k750i under Linux

Tags: linux, usb, memory, mobile-phone

I want to retrieve some photos taken with the camera on this mobile phone. But upon connection, it doesnt automount. An icon is displayed in computer:/// in Nautilus (Ubuntu/Gnome). But upon doubleclicking, I get an error about it failed to mount.

The phone is listed (by name) in `lsusb` when connected.

Comparing `ls` of /dev when the phone is connected and when its not displays some extra devices detected on the phone:

```
$ diff deva devb
4a5
> cdc-wdm0
82a84
> serial
84a87
> sg2
156a160,161
> ttyACM0
> ttyACM1
173a179,188
> usbdev6.10_ep00
> usbdev6.10_ep02
> usbdev6.10_ep04
> usbdev6.10_ep07
> usbdev6.10_ep81
> usbdev6.10_ep82
> usbdev6.10_ep83
> usbdev6.10_ep84
> usbdev6.10_ep86
> usbdev6.10_ep87
```

When connecting, the `dmesg` displays a few errors about the phone:

```
[15725.533224]  sdc: sdc1
[15756.100269] usb 6-2: reset full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 7
[15756.263469] cdc_acm 6-2:1.3: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[15756.267698] cdc_acm 6-2:1.1: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[15756.289445] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Device not ready: Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[15756.289452] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Device not ready: Add. Sense: Medium not present
[15756.289459] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1920896
[15756.289463] __ratelimit: 30 callbacks suppressed
[15756.289467] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 240112
[15756.304443] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Device not ready: Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[15756.304450] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Device not ready: Add. Sense: Medium not present
[15756.304457] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1920896
[15756.304463] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 240112
[15756.304543] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 240126
[15756.304560] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 240126
[15756.304584] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 0
[15756.304589] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 1
[15756.304600] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 0
[15756.304615] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 0
[15756.304633] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 240127
[15756.304649] Buffer I/O error on device sdc, logical block 240127
```

A /dev/sdc shows up when the phone is connected (strange it isnt displayed in the diff), but no /dev/sdc1.

The phone works as expected under Windows. Ive tried some phone related software under Linux (like Wammu) but none has succeeded in accessing it. I just want to retrieve the photos (files) no contact/sms syncing or any other advanced operation.

Google found some [success stories](http://stefans.datenbruch.de/k750i/) but nothing that helped me make progress. Tried to get help from #ubuntu but nothing there either.

- Could the memory on the phone be corrupt?
- Can the phones memory be accessed like a regular flash drive?
- ... or do I need special Linux drivers?
- Help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like Linux is trying to use your phone as a modem, which is clearly not what you are trying to achieve. Don't know about the k750i, but on the SonyEricssons I had, you could configure what kind of connection the phone should perform when plugged into a computer via USB.

Comment: Would that be a setting on the phone or on the computer? There is no dialog displayed on the phone upon connection, but it does make a sound.

Comment: That's a setting on the phone. Go to the configuration menu, choose the connections tab and find the USB entry in the menu.